# Summing String variables

Tags: php

Having brain freeze here.
This is a var_dump() for 7 string variables...

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#635 (1) { ["base_price"]=> string(3) "449" } }
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#445 (1) { ["option_delta"]=> string(2) "15" } }
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#639 (1) { ["option_delta"]=> string(2) "29" } }
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#448 (1) { ["option_delta"]=> string(2) "19" } }
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#447 (1) { ["option_delta"]=> string(2) "39" } }
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#446 (1) { ["option_delta"]=> string(2) "34" } }
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#449 (1) { ["option_delta"]=> string(2) "34" } }
```

I need the sum of these variables, and have approached it like this:

```
$totalprice = $baseprice + $procprice + $memprice + $graprice + $hdprice + $optprice + $nicprice;
```

and this:

```
$totalprice = ($baseprice + $procprice + $memprice + $graprice + $hdprice + $optprice + $nicprice);
```

and this:

```
$totalprice = (int)$baseprice + (int)$procprice + (int)$memprice + (int)$graprice + (int)$hdprice + (int)$optprice + (int)$nicprice;
```

with no joy... I know my forehead's gonna hurt from the dopeslap, but I'm ready for the relief that the pain will give me.

To add nore detail, this script (which is in Fabrik, a forms/app builder for Joomla) starts:

```
    <?php
$typ = '{rw_inquiries___product_type_id_raw}';
$pro = '{rw_inquiries___selected_processor_raw}';
$mem = '{rw_inquiries___selected_memory_raw}';
$gra = '{rw_inquiries___selected_graphics_raw}';
$hd = '{rw_inquiries___selected_hd_raw}';
$opt = '{rw_inquiries___selected_optical_raw}';
$nic = '{rw_inquiries___selected_nic_raw}';
$db =&JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery("SELECT `base_price` FROM `rw_product_types` where `id` = $typ");
$baseprice = $db->loadObjectList();
$db->setQuery("SELECT `option_delta` FROM `rw_options` where `id` = $pro");
$procprice = $db->loadObjectList();
$db->setQuery("SELECT `option_delta` FROM `rw_options` where `id` = $mem");
$memprice = $db->loadObjectList();
$db->setQuery("SELECT `option_delta` FROM `rw_options` where `id` = $gra");
$graprice = $db->loadObjectList();
$db->setQuery("SELECT `option_delta` FROM `rw_options` where `id` = $hd");
$hdprice = $db->loadObjectList();
$db->setQuery("SELECT `option_delta` FROM `rw_options` where `id` = $opt");
$optprice = $db->loadObjectList();
$db->setQuery("SELECT `option_delta` FROM `rw_options` where `id` = $nic");
$nicprice = $db->loadObjectList();
$totalprice = $baseprice + $procprice + $memprice + $graprice + $hdprice + $optprice + $nicprice;
?>
```

each of the 7 are selections from dropdowns as form fields...

and are computer components for a "configurator" selecting style of computer, processor, memory, graphics, hard drive, optical and NIC.

the "delta" options are just "adders" to the base price.

hope that helps.

Comment: They seem to be in an array...and you're accessing them using normal string variables?

Comment: Please provide more code as to how you assigned the variables.

Comment: can you provide us the name of the variable?

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the data within the returned object, not just the object itself.

```
$totalprice = ((int) $baseprice[0]->base_price + (int) $procprice[0]->option_delta);
```

That should give you basic addition of the elements.

This is deduced by looking at the object. Take $baseprice for example:

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#635 (1) { ["base_price"]=> string(3) "449" } }
```

You know it's an array with one object in it, as indicated by the array(1) in the beginning. So you access that object by saying:

```
$baseprice[0]
```

Then you see the contents between the curly braces are `[0] => object(...)` which means the first item is an object. To get the "base_price" element in that object you use -> to point to the right element:

```
$baseprice[0]->base_price
```

To add strings you can cast as int:

```
(int) $baseprice[0]->base_price
```

or use intval:

```
intval($baseprice[0]->base_price)
```

as int, you should be able to add simply by using the + character as you have demonstrated in your code.

Comment: updated. You should be able to use this example to modify your code